# jQuery prepend() method not working on certain sites in Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension, prepend

I am trying to inject a div into the body of webpages, it works perfectly on all pages that I have tried, except certain sites, namely bbc.co.uk, nytimes.com and stackoverflow.com. I suspect its because the body hasn't loaded but that doesn't really make sense as I am doing it in `$(document).ready()`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('body').prepend('<div id="tilda"></div>');
});
```

As I say this works fine as a Chrome extension injecting into most pages, just some that seem to be immune?

EDIT DUE TO COMMENT:

My inject.js file looks like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('body').prepend('<div id="tilda"></div>');
    console.log($('body'))
});
```

I am including the js files like so:

"content_scripts": [

```
    {
      "matches": ["https://*/*"],
      "js": ["js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js", "src/inject/inject.js"]
    }
 ]
```

Some websites somehow block that injection into the dom from an extension. Very confused how!

Comment: Works fine running the script on these pages through the console.

Comment: So it seems extensions are blocked somehow. I cant even get an alert box to appear on those pages. So I suppose the question becomes, how are they blocking extensions running? edit: Further reading suggests its not possible to block an extension. I have edited my question with a code snippet for my extension

Comment: 1. bbc doesn't use `https` protocol, so your content script won't be injected 2. ALWAYS use [the debugger](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tut_debugging) instead of guessing 3. Try specifying [`"run_at": "document_end"` explicitly](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#run_at)

Comment: 1. Good spot, thanks re https. 2 I wasn't just guessing, nothing was appearing in the console/debugger, don't assume. 3. Great, thanks for that.